# video read in matlab -audio output port is not relavant

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, video-processing, matlab-cvst

If i execute this statement or the similar `videoFileWriter` or even `multimediafilereader` in matlab 2012b

```
videoFileReadera = vision.VideoFileReader(filename,'AudioOutputPort',true);
```

i am getting warning as

```
Warning: The AudioOutputPort property is not relevant in this configuration of the System object.

or with AudioInputPort...
```

i know its just a warning but the object fails to read or write the audio file??

please tell me how to read a video and audio combined file and to write it back as a single video and audio combined file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;
VidObj=VideoReader('E:\workspace\mat2012b\video compression\original.mp4');
n=VidObj.NumberOfFrames;
videoFReader = vision.VideoFileReader('original.mp4');
videoFWriter = vision.VideoFileWriter('vid_new_compressed_ffd5.avi',...
   'AudioInputPort',1,'AudioDataType','int16','VideoCompressor','ffdshow video encoder','FileFormat','avi',...
   'FrameRate',videoFReader.info.VideoFrameRate);
[audio,fs]=audioread('original.mp4');
op=floor(fs/videoFReader.info.VideoFrameRate);

for i=1:n
    videoFrame= step(videoFReader);
    audios=audio( (i-1)*op + 1 : i*op , : );
    step(videoFWriter, videoFrame,audios);
end

release(videoFReader);
release(videoFWriter);
```

This above code reads an audio and video and writes back to audio and video. I tried to get .mp4 as output it didnt work. This code can give .avi and .wmv as output.

Answer (score 2):

vision.VideoFileReader support reading audio only for some file formats such as AVI, WMV, some MPEG-1/2 formats. It does not support reading audio from MP4 files.

Similarly, VideoFileWriter supports writing audio only to AVI and WMV files.

Hope this helps.

The code snippet using audioread to read audio and VideoFileReader to read video will not always guarantee synchronization between audio and video for some file formats.

Hope this helps.